# How to access appended element through another appended element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form, which allows adding up to 6 people (pic1) one by one.

[image: Pic1].

"ADD" and "+" both add the user and clear the form. This appends a piece of HTML to `#worker-container` and hides it through `display: none`.

Here's the HTML part of the code.

```
<div id="team_box_btns">
    <div id="team_add_worker_icn">
        <span id="team_add_worker"><i class="fas fa-plus-circle fa-2x"></i></span>
    </div>
    <p class="form-text-header"><span id="team_add_worker_btn" title="add employee">ADD</span> MAX OF 6 USERS </p>
</div>
<div id="worker-container">
    <div id="team_worker" class="frame_worker">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="team_name" class="form-text-header">Name</label>
                <input id="team_name" name="team_name" type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="team_s_name" class="form-text-header">Surname</label>
                <input id="team_s_name" name="team_s_name" type="text" class="form-control s_name" placeholder="" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="team_tel" class="form-text-header">Phone</label>
                <input id="team_tel" name="team_tel" type="tel" class="form-control team" placeholder="" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="team_mail" class="form-text-header">Email</label>
                <input id="team_mail" name="team_mail" type="mail" class="form-control mail" placeholder="" required>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the JS/jQ part:

```
var addWorker = $('here goes the HTML from above').appendTo($('#worker-container'));
var addWorkerIcn = $('<span id="worker_' + worker_num + '_data"><i class="fa fa-user-circle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" title="'+ name.value +' '+ s_name.value + '"></i></span>').appendTo($('#team_add_worker_icn'));
```

So after appending it looks like this:

[image: Pic2]

I want to be able to click the green top-right user icon to show the details of the added user. I know it has to do with dynamically added elements and I need to use bubbling to let jQuery know about the new element. I can do it with the dynamically added `addWorkerIcn` and it shows the alert.

$('body').on('click', addWorkerIcn, function() {
        alert('click');
        // set display: block on the addWorker element 
    });

My question is, how do I go about showing the appended `addWorker` element after clicking on another appended element?. I want it to show after clicking on the icon. I could trigger it via `click` event, but that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: You aren't delegating event here, you are just binding a click event to `body` passing some data to handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of appending the event to the newly created element, simply make a custom class for the created element and make this binding on page load:

```
$("body").on('click', '.your-class', function(e){
    var $el = $(this);
})
```

This way you won't need to append a click event to body every time, instead you'll have a single event that fires when an element of `.your-class` is clicked inside the `body` tag.

Comment: If it helped, please pick an accepted answer to help others with the same doubt.